# PHP array element comparison

Tags: php

Learning PHP and I have a question.

How does one obtain an element from an array and determine if it is equal to a static value? I have a return set from a query statement (confirmed the array has all values).

I tried:

```
<?  if($row["rowValue"] == 1) { 
    }
?>
```

I was expecting the value to be 1, but it's returning null (as if I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: when you print_r($row), what do you receive?

Comment: Seeing "$row" makes me think you're pulling it from a result set... can you show the code where you get the result set?  Are you using mysqli?  What you have there should work as long as "$row['rowValue']" has a value.

Comment: Is the column name `rowValue` ?

Comment: The dump on the row is ["hasReport"]=> string(1) "0". Which is odd, because the d type in the db is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there; something like this should confirm it for you:

```
echo "<p>Q: Does ".$row["rowValue"]." = 1?</p>";
if($row["rowValue"] == 1) {
    echo "<p>A: Yes ".$row["rowValue"]." does equal 1</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>A: No, '".$row["rowValue"]."' does not equal 1</p>";
}
```

If that's still returning 'No' you could try viewing the whole of the `$row` array by doing a var dump of the array like so:

```
var_dump($row);
```

This will give you detailed output of how the array is built and you should be able to see if you are calling the correct element within the array.

Comment: The dump on the row is  ["hasReport"]=> string(1) "0". Which is odd, because the d type in the db is an integer.

Comment: If you pulled this out of a database your array will automatically assume the value is a string, rather than an int. This doesn't matter if you are using a `if($row["rowValue"] == 1)` comparison (it would if you were comparing like so: `if($row["rowValue"] === 1)` [here's a little info on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)) as you'll see if you change my code to == 0 it will return true for you in your case.

Comment: So I did a print_r of the variable. It prints 0 when it's zero, and nothing when it's 1. I can't quite understand why. So I changed the comparison to == 0 and it works when it is 0. Any idea why that would be? It's a TINYINT, maxlength of 4.

Comment: it looks like the DB query is returning it as 0, check to make sure the query is returning the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

What is returning `null`?

Try this:

```
if($row["rowValue"] === 1) { ... }
```

Make sure there is an element in `$row` called `rowValue`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
<?  if($row[0]["theNameOfAColumn"] == 1) { 
    }
?>
```

Usually databases return rows like row[0], row[1], row[2], etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are doing, but try using array_filp() which will Exchanges all keys with their associated values
than you can do like

```
if($row["rowValue"] == 1) {
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're pulling it from mysqli_fetch_row then it wants a number, not a column name.  If it's being pulled from mysqli_fetch_array then it will accept a column name.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php